# Table does not exist error thrown on executing powershell script that queries MySql database

Tags: mysql, powershell

Am running powershell script that queries MySql database and outputs results in email. However, I am facing this error for new query which works perfectly fine when ran on MySql client but throws

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "2" argument(s): "Table 'bugs.PROFILES' doesn't exist"
```

Below is the query that works just fine in SqlYOG -

```
SELECT b.bug_id                           AS Bug_Id, 
       b.bug_status                       AS STATUS, 
       b.resolution                       AS Resolution, 
       q.realname                         AS Reporter, 
       p.realname                         AS Assigned_To, 
       b.short_desc                       AS Summary, 
       DATE_FORMAT(b.deadline, '%m/%d/%Y')AS Deadline 
FROM   bugs b 
       INNER JOIN PROFILES p 
               ON b.assigned_to = p.userid 
       INNER JOIN PROFILES q 
               ON b.reporter = q.userid 
WHERE  ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST', 'REOPENED' ) 
         AND short_desc NOT LIKE '%Program:%' 
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       ) 
        OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
             AND short_desc NOT LIKE '%Program:%' 
             AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
                                  CURDATE() ) 
ORDER  BY bug_status ASC
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the powershell that you are using, it's impossible to guess what you are doing.

Comment: @StephenP It does not matter right now because the query is failing with same error in SqlYog too. It was working fine before and now all of a sudden this error.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions issue.
Check that the account executing the powershell script has read permissions to that table.